# TLS on vsftpd in browser does not exist: 530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd on debian 8 and I configured it in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` like so:

```
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
use_localtime=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/ftproot/anonymous
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
pasv_address=192.168.133.130
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40010
pasv_promiscuous=YES
pasv_enable=YES
ssl_enable=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
allow_anon_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
anon_max_rate=30000
local_max_rate=30000
idle_session_timeout=300
max_per_ip=50
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
log_ftp_protocol=YES
debug_ssl=YES
```

When I want to login with `filezilla` with certificate this is ok. But when I use the web like:

```
ftp://user1@192.168.133.130
```

I have the following error:

```
530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.
```

Comment: Forcing SSL and using `ftp://` seems to be the problem here, I guess.  Did you try to specify URL scheme `ftps://` instead of `ftp://`?

Comment: I used `ftps:// ` So it goes to google searching !!!

Comment: Ah, dang.  At least Firefox does not seem to support `ftps`-scheme.  I don't even think it actually supports FTP over SSL (eventually it's a _Web_-Browser, isn't it? :)

Comment: Ok I am in chromium now... So that problem again... This is necessary for me....

Comment: Again, those are _Web_-browers.  You won't be able to do this unless you add some third-party software.  Searching for FTPS in Firefox Add-Ons is not too unfruitful, though.

Comment: SO I have to use some app like filezilla... haven't I?

Comment: NO, as I said, you could install a Browser-AddOn capable of handling FTPS, like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/ for Firefox (I'm sure, there's something similar for Chrome, Google will find you something).